# How to retrieve column value by passing another column value with IN clause in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a scenario that to read a column from DataFrame by using another column from same DataFrame through where condition and this value pass through as IN condition to select same value from another DataFrame and how can I achieve in spark DataFrame.

In SQL it will be like:

```sql
select distinct(A.date) from table A where A.key in (select B.key from table B where cond='D');
```

I tried like below:

```scala
val Bkey: DataFrame = b_df.filter(col("cond")==="D").select(col("key"))
```

I have table A data in a_df DataFrame and table B data in b_df DataFrame. How can I pass variable Bkey value to outer query and achieve in Spark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a semi join:

```
val result = a_df.join(b_df.filter(col("cond")==="D"), Seq("key"), "left_semi").select("date").distinct()
```

Comment: Thanks so much for reply and advise, what if column "key" has different name in table A & B ? for example table A has name as key but, table B has tkey but has same value in both tables. can we have Seq("key", "tkey') ?

Comment: then use a_df.key === b_df.tkey instead of Seq("key")

Comment: val result = a_df.join(b_df.filter(col("cond")==="D"),a_df.key === b_df.tkey , "left_semi").select("date").distinct() Is this understanding correct ??

Comment: looks fine, you can test it

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will test and get back with findings.